# Composer install private repository on IIS by Jenkins CI

Tags: windows, git, iis, jenkins, composer-php

I am trying to install composer dependencies from private bitbucket repository by `composer install` with lines below in composer.json on my IIS server (triggered by Jenkins CI).

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "ssh://git@bitbucket.org/company/repo-name.git"
    }
],
```

The result is:

```
Failed to execute git clone --mirror "ssh://git@bitbucket.org/company/web.git" "C:/Users/myusername/AppData/Local/Composer/vcs/ssh---company-bitbucket.org-repo-name.git/"
Cloning into bare repository 'C:/Users/myusername/AppData/Local/Composer/vcs/ssh---company-bitbucket.org-repo-name.git'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Is it possible to link private.ppk with composer without need of ssh-agent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins CI is logged in as sysuser, so navigate to its .ssh folder and edit config file : C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.ssh\config (if "config" file not exists, create it)

Store your key to e.g. keys subfolder: C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.ssh\keys\bitbucket

In config file add these lines:

```
Host bitbucket.org
HostName bitbucket.org
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/keys/bitbucket
```